# How to build a 32 bit exe file with 64 bit windows 10?

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I wrote a code in python with pyqt framework and make an exe file with pyinstaller out of if. Since I have 64-bit windows, the exe file is 64 bit as well, but here is the problem: The company I want to give the code to has 32-bit windows 7, so the application does not run on their machine. I heard I can build a 32-bit exe file with py2exe but I don't know how. How can I build a 32-bit exe file with any package (like py2exe, actually it does not matter) with 64bit machine? Just do not suggest to install 32-bit python. Thanks.